# Visual Studio WPF designer crashes when using a + in a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm

My Visual Studio 2010 designer crashes with this error:

```
Error   3   Type 'vm:MessageViewModel+MessageAction' was not found.
```

This is the line causing the error:

```
<Button Content="View" Command="{Binding Path=ActionCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static vm:MessageViewModel+MessageAction.OpenView}"/>
```

Keep in mind the program compiles and runs fine. The parameter is even passed correctly to the command.

The enum is inside a class so I need to use the plus sign to reference it. This is the class structure:

```
public class MessageViewModel : ModelWrapViewModel<MessageModel>
{
    private ICommand _actionCommand;

    public enum MessageAction
    {
        OpenView,
        OpenNote,
        OpenAcknowledge,
        Cancel,
        Save,
        Acknowledge
    }

    public ICommand ActionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_actionCommand == null)
            {
                _actionCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => this.DoSomething((MessageAction)param),
                    param => true
                );
            }
            return _actionCommand;
        }
    }

}
```

Just wondering if there is a reason this doesn't work in the VS designer. If I move the enum outside of the of the `MessageViewModel` class the designer doesn't crash.

Comment: Can you not do like this? `vm:MessageViewModel.MessageAction.OpenView`

Comment: No that is not syntactically correct in WPF. If you want to reference types inside of classes in xaml you use a `+`. Using a `.` won't even compile so that's a step backwards.

Answer (score 1):

visual studio can be a pain sometimes no? Not sure if this will help but can you make it a Dynamic Resource so it only loads at run time. Hope this helps - Rick 
CommandParameter="{DynamicResource {x:Static vm:MessageViewModel+MessageAction.OpenView}}"/>

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't work for me either in the designer or when I run the program.